# How sensitive is information on a system's architecture?

Tags: information-gathering

How much easier would it be to break into a system if you knew the following information?

- Processor architecture / family
- Operating system
- Libraries used
- Application programming language
- Standardised protocols used

I'd like to know **how much easier** and **which components are most sensitive** in this regard (subjective answers OK). Assume that, other than this information, reasonable effort was made to make the system secure, e.g. secure protocols and keys would be used where appropriate.

Comment: Not much easier. Remember shannon's maxim: the enemy knows the system. Don't fall into the trap of security through obscurity by trying to obscure things like the programming language in use. Note also that many of these can be tested for remotely.

Comment: @forest Absolutely. My question is more along the lines of, assuming I _don't_ rely on security through obscurity, what is the impact of letting an attacker know about the system design? "Minimal" would be an OK answer, but I'd like some more details.

Comment: @forest you're right, I really mean "processor architecture". I'll change it.

Comment: The answer is pretty much the same. The processor architecture is even easier to find out.

Comment: Completely disagree with the answers here saying it doesn't matter. All this information does matter and is in fact listed as Low level security risks. By providing this information I now can easily find an exploit for your system and requires no effort on my part. So are you using a processor that is vulnerable to spectre? Cool this is a hard to mitigate exploit so guess I'll be using this. What libraries is your web app using, well lets find a CVE for one.  All the information you listed are KEY to finding an exploit - penetration testers request this information prior to engagements

Comment: @McMatty - no, protecting this information doesn't really matter because it is so trivial to find out. Penetration testers may request it prior to an engagement, but that is solely to save time/money. A real world attacker can be assumed to know it.

Comment: @McMatty If you noticed, I did say the only time it mattered was to avoid simple automated mass-exploitation, but doing that simply involves tweaking some settings in your server config (not displaying version info, etc). It's not a real improvement in **security**. For a pentester, finding out this information is trivial. Going through extensive steps (and yes, it would be extensive) to hide this information would be about as good a use of your time as finding a witch doctor to curse your adversaries.

Comment: @RoryAlsop what technique do use that is trivial to determine a web applications libraries being used and underlying CPU architecture? Honest question because in my own experience that requires finding an exploit on the web application to get a shell and I don't believe this should be classed as a trivial thing to do.

Comment: @McMatty While I don't know what Rory Alsop uses, I myself use various popular fingerprinting tools. Nearly any vulnerability scanner has them in various forms, and designing a new one is not too difficult. As for the CPU architecture, just hazard a guess that it's x86 and you'll be right the vast majority of the time. Otherwise, do OS fingerprinting using things like sequence number patterns and TCP options to narrow down the possible architectures (e.g. Solaris? Probably SPARC or x86).

Comment: I don't believe this question is primarily opinion-based. How sensitive information on a system's architecture can be objectively answered, as can be seen in my answer which does not involve any opinionated or subjective claims.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**This information is not sensitive.**

An attacker would gain very little by knowing these facts beforehand. Many of them are either not relevant to their campaign, or trivial to detect remotely, even if the configuration is not published. In order to answer adequately, you may want to elaborate on what you mean by "break in". Is the attacker attempting to bypass authorization remotely? Do they have a local process running on the system and are attempting to elevate privileges? Are they trying to root a commercial embedded system that they have purchased and have physical access to? Hiding this information may slow down someone who is trying to [jailbreak a commercial system](https://cturt.github.io/ps4.html) for a short amount of time by forcing them to spend time reverse engineering it, but it will do nothing against an attacker with a local shell trying to get root.

There is only one situation where hiding certain information is beneficial, and that is when an attacker is attempting mass-exploitation of a remote vulnerability. Having your application withhold its exact version can decrease the chance that an army of bots scanning the entire internet will attempt to exploit you. This will *not* protect against anyone who is looking to exploit you specifically, however.

## Details you are trying to hide

> Processor family

The processor *family* itself tends not to matter. The overwhelming majority of exploits, of all kinds, will work equally well on Skylake as on Kabylake. If you're talking about processor *architectures*, then it starts to matter, as MIPS shellcode will not work on an ARM system, and vice versa. However, this is not something that should be obscured, as the majority of servers and systems in general are running x86, mobile systems tend to run ARM, and embedded systems often run MIPS.

> Operating system

Whether or not the operating system even needs to be known depends on what is being exploited. If a web app is being attacked, the operating system may not even be relevant. A SQLi vulnerability in a popular web platform will work equally well on Windows, Linux, FreeBSD, Solaris, or any other operating system that can run the vulnerable application. If the attacker is trying to attack the system itself to elevate privileges, it may be necessary to know the operating system. This information can be obtained remotely through a technique known as [OS detection](https://nmap.org/book/osdetect.html), or OS fingerprinting.

> Libraries used

There are some libraries that will generally always be used. You will practically never find something that does not link against `libc`. A program doing math will likely use `libm`. A program that accepts user input via CLI will likely use `libreadline`. There are not many exceptions. If an attacker is trying to exploit a program, they only need to know the libraries in use if they are exploiting a particular vulnerability in the library. It's easy to check which libraries a program needs, as the list is encoded into the executable itself. Various scripts like [`ldd`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ldd.1.html) can gather this information from an executable.

> Application programming language

The programming language for a vulnerable program may matter, depending on the type of exploit that is being used. A language like PHP which does its own memory management (is [memory-safe](http://trevorjim.com/why-safe-languages-are-the-best-way-to-achieve-memory-safety/)) tells you that you will not need to attempt a stack overflow, as memory is managed. A C program on the other hand may be vulnerable to such a bug, as it is lower level. Knowing the language itself is neither necessary, nor sufficient for exploitation. The overlap in knowledge between a person who knows enough about a program to exploit it, and a person who does not know the language it uses, is zero.

> Standardised protocols used

Some protocols are more vulnerable than others. [DCCP for example](https://seclists.org/oss-sec/2017/q1/471) has a history of nasty vulnerabilities. Rather than attempting to hide the protocols you are using, it would be far better to disable the unnecessary ones, as an attacker can simply attempt a connection with said protocol to see if it is supported. If the connection fails, it is either unsupported, or the port is closed. Either way, attacking the protocol itself will not be possible if it is not open and supported.

## Types of attackers

There are different types of attackers. For this answer, let's split up the types of attackers into local, remote, and physical, and see what position they are in to gather the information they need.

#### Local attacker

A local attacker is running a process on your system. They want to elevate their privileges, or move laterally to other users. They may or may not be sandboxed. A local attacker is one of the most dangerous, as they have access to any information the operating system willingly gives out.

- Processor family - Unnecessary, but can be retrieved in `/proc/cpuinfo`.
- Operating system - If they are running locally, they most likely already know the operating system.
- Libraries - If they have access to the executable, then can run `ldd` or [`readelf`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/readelf.1.html) on it.
- Language - Checking the libraries in use gives away the runtime, revealing the language.
- Protocols - Using the [`socket()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/socket.2.html) syscall can allow testing if a given protocol is supported.

#### Remote attacker

A remote attacker is trying to compromise a server. Their only interaction with the target is over the network, subject to any firewall rules that may be in play. They want to gain unauthorized access to the system by exploiting vulnerabilities in remotely running services.

- Processor family - Unnecessary to know, but can probably be guessed.
- Operating system - Many tools can remotely reveal the operating system being used.
- Libraries - Very few remote exploits need to know the specific libraries being used.
- Language - If they know a service well enough to attack it, they know the language.
- Protocols - An attacker can attempt to connect using a particular protocol. If it fails, it is either not supported or firewalled off. The attacker does not care about the distinction.

#### Physical attacker

A physical attacker has your device in their hands. They may be trying to reverse engineer it and jailbreak it to expand its functionality or access secrets it is storing. They can open the device, look at the labels on the components, [dump firmware](https://jcjc-dev.com/2016/06/08/reversing-huawei-4-dumping-flash/), and possibly even [attach the CPU to a debugger](https://www.embedded.com/introduction-to-jtag/). This is the most powerful class of attacks. There is generally no way to prevent a physical attacker from gaining detailed information about your system, given enough time.

- Processor family - This can be determined by reading the CPU's datasheet.
- Operating system, libraries, language, and protocols - Dumping the firmware reveals this.

## Summary

In general, this information is either easy to find out, not necessary to know, or difficult to hide. There are far better ways to improve your security. Now, what you *should* do, rather than hiding the following:

- Processor family - Make sure you are using a modern processor with [valuable security features](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/171670/106285) like NX, SMEP, and RDRAND. A good operating system can take advantage of processor security features to enhance your security. CISC systems are [easier to exploit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return-oriented_programming#On_the_x86_architecture) using ROP. Systems with out-of-order and [speculative execution](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/176803/106285) can be vulnerable to side-channel attacks.
- Operating system - Use a secure operating system, kept up to date and configured securely. OpenBSD is more secure than an old Windows server. Linux with [grsecurity](https://grsecurity.net) is more secure than a poorly maintained CentOS system. A custom kernel configuration or whitelisted modules can allow you to disable unnecessary drivers and other risky features.
- Libraries used - Ensure all your libraries are kept up to date. If a vulnerability is discovered in a library, update it and restart any application that is running and which links against it.
- Application programming language - When possible, use a language that is memory-safe. It is harder to get things wrong when writing in python than it is when writing in C.
- Standardised protocols used - Only enable the protocols you need. Unnecessary protocols may be exploitable locally or remotely. If you have whitelisted your protocols to only the core basics necessary to run adequately, exploiting you through a networking vulnerability will be much harder.

While there is no reason to *reveal* all this information (assuming you are not expecting collaboration, where revealing information can help people point out bugs for you to fix), some of the details you mention are either so irrelevant or so easy to detect that you would have to go to excessive lengths to hide that information. Simply disabling version information is one thing. Wasting effort trying to prevent someone from knowing if you are on an x86 system or a SPARC system is just unnecessary.

Some resources you might be interested in:

- [What is the best way to explain (a non-technical person) the risk of leaking version information?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/127638/106285)
- [Is it safe to reveal information about the OS and the software you use?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/69276/106285)
- [Hiding version - valuable or just security by obscurity?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/14709/106285)
- [The valid role of obscurity](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/2430/106285)
- [Is displaying what server I am running on the error pages a security risk?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/4940/106285)
- [OWASP - Testing for Web Application Fingerprint](https://wiki.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_for_Web_Application_Fingerprint_%28OWASP-IG-004%29)